# T-SQL Query That Works Perfectly Suddenly Fails In a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

DISCLAIMER:  Please bear with me.  I'm relatively inexperienced with SQL/T-SQL and SQL Server, so if this looks a little strange, that's why.

I created a query that basically synchronizes some Active Directory user data with two tables.  It starts by creating a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE #ADUsers ( ... )
```

Then the data is pulled from Active Directory and inserted in #ADUsers using code that was somewhat inspired by [this blog post](http://www.bravesoft.com/blog/?p=24).  At this point, there is a lot of unnecessary data in the temp table that includes thing like inactive/disabled and service accounts and I was having some trouble removing it from within the OPENQUERY statement, so the results were sanitized using a SELECT ... INTO statement using the WHERE clause to remove unnecessary data then put the result into another temporary table.  The final step is a merge statement, to update a "master" table.

This query, though long and messy, works perfectly!  The next step was to make this a stored procedure and maybe create a trigger of some kind that would run the stored procedure and semi-regular intervals to keep the data up to date.

When I turn it into a stored procedure and execute, however, it shows an error about unclosed quotes and incorrect syntax.

```
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'SELECT CN, givenName, SN, objectCategory, SAMAccountName, mail, department, manager, OU, userAccountControl
FROM 'LDAP://DC=domain, DC=local'
WHERE objectCategory = 'Person' 
                        '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT CN, givenName, SN, objectCategory, SAMAccountName, mail, department, manager, OU, userAccountControl
FROM 'LDAP:/'.
```

This error isn't thrown when the query is run by itself outside a stored procedure.  When put inside a stored procedure and executed, the above error is shown repeatedly.

I'd love to know what is causing these errors and how to fix this.

Thank you in advance for any help and advice!

Comment: Double up the single-quotes.

Comment: So what did you do when turning it into a stored procedure? Should just need to add `CREATE PROC Foo AS ...` before the working code.

Comment: @GoatCO I did.  I even tripled it.  It made no difference.

Comment: Martin's question is better than my response, I wasn't really looking at your question just saw those singles.  Post the procedure and the real problem will be apparent.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's what I did.  It's supposed to just work after that but it doesn't.  I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that the quotation marks are not closed properly, double the quotation mark around LDAP://DC=domain, DC=local and Person:

```
SELECT CN, givenName, SN, objectCategory, SAMAccountName, mail, 
department, manager, OU, userAccountControl FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain, DC=local''
WHERE objectCategory = ''Person''
```

Comment: I doubled up the quotes, double checked everything to make sure it was closed.  The result was the same.

Comment: Can you please copy paste that part of the query

Comment: It's the same as the code in the [blog post](http://www.bravesoft.com/blog/?p=24).  The only difference is that I added more AD properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what was causing the error, but I somehow got it running.  All I did was to remove the `BEGIN` and `END` that are just before and at the end of the query in the store procedure and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you simply need to use two single quotes around the embedded strings.

```
'SELECT CN, givenName, SN, objectCategory, SAMAccountName, mail, department, manager, OU, userAccountControl
     FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain, DC=local''
     WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' '
```

I would guess that this is running from within a:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ...);
```

Comment: Yes, it is within a `SELECT ... FROM OPENQUERY` statement.  I learned the hardway about doubling up single quotes on those statements.  I double checked everything to make sure all quotes were closed and made sure that two single quotes were used.  The result was still the same.